# Magento2 : Data Not saving in Custom Table

Tags: magento2, database, custom

I have created a custom module and trying to save data but not saved data into `custom_table`. I don't know why? I compared same code with my previous Modules Everything is same.

> Here is my installSchema.php

```
 public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('table_name')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('table_name')
            )->addColumn(
                'row_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'primary'  => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'unsigned' => false,
                ],
                'Missing Order ID'
            )->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'unsigned' => false,
                ],
                'Qoute ID'
            )->addColumn(
                'reserved_order_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'unsigned' => false,
                ],
                'Reserved Order ID'
            )->addColumn(
                'customer_email',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                100,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                ],
                'Costumer Email'
            )->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATE,
                null,
                [

                    'nullable' => false,
                ],
                'Order Date'
            )->addColumn(
                'base_grand_total',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                null,
                [
                    'nullable' => false,
                ],
                'Grand Total'
            )->setComment('Missing Orders');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }


 $installer->endSetup();
}
```

here is my code to save data

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order    = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
        $quote    = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());
        $order    = null;
        if (empty($order)) {
            try {
                $rowData = $this->_missingOrdersFactory->create();
                $rowData->setEntityId($quote->getEntityId());
                $rowData->setReservedOrderId($quote->getReservedOrderId());
                $rowData->setCustomerEmail($quote->getCustomerEmail());
                $rowData->setCreatedAt($quote->getCreatedAt());
                $rowData->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal());
                $rowData->save();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($rowData->getData());
                exit;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }
```

> print_r($rowData->getDdata) is returning me

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 200
    [reserved_order_id] => 000000168
    [customer_email] => waqarcui@gmail.com
    [created_at] => 2019-07-03 04:29:03
    [base_grand_total] => 105.0000
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please make sure that you are getting empty $order?

Comment: yes my code interrupts at exit() it means if condtion is true

Comment: Did you do cache flush?

Comment: yes i really did this\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not setting the `'identity' => true` in your `installschema.php`, that's why it won't auto-increment since you're not adding data to `row_id` that may be the reason your data is not saving.

> Your primary key field should be like this.

```
          ->addColumn(
                    'row_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary'  => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                    ],
                    'Missing Order ID'
                )
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i add data to database using sql its showing fine in admin Grid

Comment: ok can you share your whole file code for saving data rather than piece of code and can you please tell me what are you getting in `$order` and `$quote` variable

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: what's your event name?

Comment: `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

Comment: mark it as accepted if it's solved your issue so it will help others

Comment: my issue isn't resolved yet that i am waiting for solution

Comment: have you made the changes to `installschema.php` ?

Comment: thank you its working fine now